# ASP.NET AJAX "as you type" functionality

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autofilter

Although this is FAQ i still couldn't find a suitable solution. I'd like to filter out a list (rendered with ListView control placed to UpdatePanel) as user types something in TextBox. [This blog post](http://remy.supertext.ch/2007/06/see-search-results-as-you-type-an-aspnet-ajax-control/) describes exactly what i need - raise a postback after a specified number of characters added. But the implementation has a few minor drawbacks. I'm surprised AutoCompleteExtender isn't generic enough to handle such cases and that i cannot find other out-of-the-box solutions. So what would you recommend as an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at the jQuery autocomplete plugin - you should be able to use some of the code there to get you started.
[Plugin page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete)

Comment: Yeah, it's a nifty thing but i'll keep looking for server-side helper control to not reinvent a wheel (can't believe it's a rare scenario).